# Android SQLite Select query speed

Tags: android, sqlite, optimization, select

I would like help speeding up a fairly simple select query in my `SQLite` database.

The query is searching a table of approx 6500 rows and currently returns in about 600ms.  I don't know if that is acceptable or not, but I had hoped that it would be faster than that.  I will be putting this into an `AsyncTask` eventually, but wanted to optimize as much as possible.  In the code snippet below you can see what I have tried.
KEY_songPath is indexed.

```
public ArrayList<Song> getCurrentDirSongs(String currentDir) {
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
ArrayList<Song> songsList = new ArrayList<Song>();

String selectQuery = "";
int strLength = currentDir.length();
    //selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SONGS + " WHERE (" + KEY_songPath + " >= '" + currentDir + "')";
    //selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SONGS + " WHERE (" + KEY_songPath + " GLOB '" + currentDir + "*')";
    //selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SONGS + " WHERE (" + KEY_songPath + " LIKE '" + currentDir + "%')";
    selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SONGS + " WHERE " + KEY_ID +
                    " IN (SELECT " + KEY_ID +" FROM "+ TABLE_SONGS + " WHERE length(" + KEY_songPath + ")>= "+ strLength +") AND " + 
                    "(" + KEY_songPath + " LIKE '" + currentDir + "%')";

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Song song = new Song();
        song.setSongTitle(cursor.getString(1));
        song.setSongPath(cursor.getString(2));
        song.setSongArtist(cursor.getString(3));
        song.setSongAlbum(cursor.getString(4));
        song.setTrackNumber(cursor.getString(5));
        song.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)));
        song.setAlbumID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)));
        song.setArtistID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)));
        song.setSongCheckedStatus(Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(9)));
        song.setSongPosition(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(10)));
        song.setSongDuration(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(11)));
        // Adding song to list
        songsList.add(song);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
Log.d("AMCDatabase Database Handler: ", "SongsList.size(): "+ getSongsCount("SongsList") + " Time: " + estimatedTime + "ms");
// return contact list
return songsList;
```

}

This has returned with the following result:
SongsList.size(): 6390 Time: 588ms

Any help gratefully received!

P.S This may all be a non-issue - is that time of a second acceptable to query and 6000 values to an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what's wrong with your third commented query statement? I'm not sure I understand why you're querying for KEY_ID and then querying again based on that.

Comment: Hi Geobits.  I was just messing around trying to speed it up.  Query 3 and 4 return in similar times.  The idea was to create a smaller subset of the table

Comment: Ah. The reason I asked is that in your nested query, you're running the `LIKE currentDir%` part on the full 6k rows anyway, so I can't see how it would be an improvement over the third one. Either way, like you said in your update, it may be a non-issue. It's hard to say what an acceptable time is, though. Especially if you're going to go async with it(which you should), what is acceptable to you? I'd worry about getting it all done first. Speed comes later, if it's needed. It's probably not the query, though. Check the timer after the query and before the loop to see what you get.

Comment: Not related, but you really should close that `Cursor`.

Comment: Your estimatedTime includes the call to getReadableDatabase() which is probably adding some overhead to your measurement. You can confirm this by moving `long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();` to just before when you are doing the rawQuery. Also, you should consider doing `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();` only once at an earlier time, outside getCurrentDirSongs().

Comment: Suraj C- interestingly I had changed the code before I read you message to exactly that.  The overhead of opening the db was 14ms, so not too drastic all things considered.  Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm wondering if I should just return the key column and grab the data one at a time from the activity and service when its required.  Perhaps I'm going about it all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using nested `SELECT` statments, instead see if you can use `JOIN`.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Songs AS s1 JOIN Songs AS s2 ON s1.KEY_ID = s2.KEY_ID WHERE length (s2.KEY_SONGPATH) >= " + strLength + ") AND s1.KEY_SONGPATH LIKE '" + currentDir + "%'
```

Comment: any suggestions how?  doesn't seem appropriate in this case to normalize the data, I only want to filter the table by songPath.  Is it possible to use temp tables?  Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: PaulG, thanks for the example, much appreciated.  However, it returns marginally slower - 800ms.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a subquery; it doesn't make anything faster because it still has to do the same checks.

Dont use `LENGTH(column) >= value` because it isn't faster than the `LIKE` check, and cannot be indexed.

To speed up the `LIKE`, put an index on the `KEY_ID` column.
Because `LIKE` is case-insensitive by default, you have to use `COLLATE NOCASE` when creating the index
(see the [CREATE INDEX documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)).